# Counter that doesn't refresh with the page

Tags: javascript, random, var

Recently I'm making the website which should contain the counter of population.
The idea is to add a random number(1-10) every second.

I've come up with the following piece, but it refreshes every time I restart the page.

```
var population = 150
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) +1;

var t = setInterval(function() {
    population += random;
    document.getElementById("pop").innerHTML = population;
}, 1000);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Save the value in `localStorage`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var population = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("population")) || 150;
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) +1;

var t = setInterval(function() {
    population += random;
    document.getElementById("pop").innerHTML = population;
}, 1000);
localStorage.setItem("population", population);
```

Using local storage and parse Int you can get value after oge refresh also

Comment: probably want the setting to local storage to be in the interval execution